# Rfacebook - getFriends retrieve fewer friends of mine

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `Rfacebook` library to get friends of mine. I selected "unversioned" as API version and select all check box in `Get Access token` but it return only 5 friends out of 170 friends. I am using below statement to retrieve the friends

my_friend <- getFriends(token, simplify=T)

I read on multiple post that some "`user_friend`" permission is required.

I did the same with my wife facebook account and it return all the friends even mutual friends (which I can't retrieve using my own facebook access token). It seems that there is some problem in facebook security settings.

Please help to identify the issue.

Thanks....

### Adding more info

> I opened Graph API explorer directly and select "unversioned" as
>   version and generate access token using "Get Access Token". I used
>   that token to get the friend list.

Answer (score 1):

Thaat's not a problem with security settings... Since the Graph API v2.0 from April 30th 2014, the endpoint `/me/friends` only the friends which are also using the same app. Hence, you seem to use a Graph API >= v2.0 app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> The `/me/friends` endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app.

Comment: Having confusion......How I am able to retrieve my wife facebook friends even mutual friends? I am not able to retrieve those mutual friends. I did the same steps to retrieve friends from both the facebook account.

Comment: Then your wife must use the same app, i.e. given permissions. What kind of app have you been using to get the Access Token(s)?

Comment: I am building website.. My confusion is why I am not able to retrieve the same friends with my facebook account which I am able to retrieve the same with my wife fb account with same steps.